# Hard questions from an IQ test

Tags: pattern, visual

I have edited the post to reduce the number of questions (I only kept the ones that were already answered) and I am creating a new post

The questions are from the test taken from the website:
http://www.iq-brain.com/example/1

1:
[image]

2:
[image]

5:
[image]

Comment: Why did I got 4DV? What did I do wrong? I am new in this forum. I want to leran with my mistakes. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: IQ test questions do not tend to be well-received here, as they rely most of the time on a random logic that is neither fun nor creative. People here will prefer something that is either entertaining, or creative, which can be something that you created yourself or something that is not yours but that you found really awesome and want to share.

Comment: @rrp there is nothing wrong with your question. the thing is you put them all in one section. that is why is closed as too broad. be specific to one question edit and update it then you can vote for reopening.

Comment: I have edited the post and kep only 2 questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.

> Bottom left. When the first two shapes are superimposed, regions that are only occupied by one shape are red, by both are white.

5.

> Bottom left. Purple\Blue is widen, turn tip black. Green is rotate, Red is turn body yellow.

Comment: Great, JMP. Your answers to the questions #2 and #5 seems to be correct.

Comment: Why's my answer got a DV?

Comment: I do not know what is a DV. I am new to this forum. I just click to accept your answer. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: DV is down-vote. See the two arrows above the green tick - one means upvote(+10 to me) and the other means downvote (-2 to me, -1 to whoever). If it was you, the downvote arrow will be purple. You can either click it again or click the up button, unless the answer has been locked, which is different.

Comment: It was not me. Actually, I tried to upvote, but I was not allowed (I got a message that I have less than 15 reputation)...Anyway, I really appreciate your answers. They were useful! Do you have any idea of the remaining 5 questions?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer for 1:

> there is a loop, pentagon, rectangle, triangle, and circle.
>  so the answer should be to complete all the shapes. there is pentagon already given in the last one. so the missing parts are the remaining shapes. but as you can see there is 2 part is blank in the first one. so it is not possible to answer. please update the question with the missing part.

Answer for the 2:

> it is C shape with hollow circle and rectangle combination. the first
>  part is filled shape in both the option and second part is the unfilled shape and you
>  need to combine both of them to get the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sayed. I just reproduced the question as it was on the test. I did not remove any part of it. I believe it should be possible to find the solution as the way it is presented...

Comment: In fact, I believe that the bottom left square of the question was kept blank intentionaly to make it harder. As I understood this question, there should be 1 of each element per line/column (1 pentagon, 1 rectangle and 1 triangle). So I believe the bottom left square would be a triangle.

Comment: I believe the answer would be a rectangle (because it is the missing element in the 3rs column). The problem is that there are 3 rectangles among the possible answers and I could not find the logic of which one would be the correct one.

Comment: @rrp as you can see in your 1st question, in the option you can choose only one form the options. if the two part of the puzzle was missing then it will say choose the two. it is not your fault, it is the bug in the puzzle site. so don't worry